# STM32 code not working, while loop, delay problems

Tags: stm32, microcontroller

Currently, I'm facing a weird problem with the STM32. I just generated code with the STM32Cube IDE for the chosen MCU (STM32L031G6). I nearly didn't change anything, except configuring one GPIO as output and trying to let a connected LED blink.

Now the problem:

- If I run the code, nothing happens, no blink at all.
- Stepping through the code, I can enable the LED once when the WritePin is called. Afterwards, just one step further, the LED is off again, although there is no further WritePin call executed. The LED never gets back on again.

What can be the problem with this code? There is nothing special about it? Did I miss something which is required for generated STM32 code?

For the following code I removed any unused line and comment.

```
#include "main.h"
void SystemClock_Config(void); 
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

int main(void) {
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  while(1) {
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);

  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void) {   
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};   
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;   
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)   {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2; 
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;    
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;   
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;   
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void) {   
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_Pin;   
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;   
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;   
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;   
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void Error_Handler(void) {
  __disable_irq();   
  while (1) {}   
}
```

**Update 1:**
As seen in the comments the HAL_Delay is not working properly. But how to fix it? And why the code does not let the led flicker when the HAL_Delay is removed?

**Update 2:**
It is also not possible to use the loop the following way, but the led is not turned on in any way.

```
while (1) {
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin);
}
```

See the following images for the configuration.
[image: Pin Configuration Overview]
[image: GPIO Configuration]
[image: NVIC Configuration]
[image: SYS Configuration]
[image: Clock Configuration]

**Update 3:**
When executing the code on the STM32L031G6, the debugger stops pretty soon. Stepping through the code works (sometimes). Here is the debug log when clicking "Run" in the STM32Cube IDE.

```
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V7.58 Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V7.58 (DLL compiled Nov  4 2021 16:23:13)

Command line: -port 2331 -s -device STM32L031G6 -endian little -speed 4000 -if swd -vd
-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      localhost only
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               on
Init regs on start:            off
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               on
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 STM32L031G6
Target interface:              SWD
Target interface speed:        4000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link V11 compiled Dec  9 2021 14:14:49
Hardware: V11.00
S/N: 261014681
OEM: SEGGER-EDU
Feature(s): FlashBP, GDB
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.34 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...
Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection...Connected to 127.0.0.1
GDB closed TCP/IP connection (Socket 1132)
Connected to 127.0.0.1
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x1FF000FC (Data = 0x89B8D002)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x1FF000FC (Data = 0xD002)
Received monitor command: WriteDP 0x2 0xF0
O.K.
Received monitor command: ReadAP 0x2
O.K.:0xF0000003
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x1FF000E4 (Data = 0x05408A28)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x1FF000E4 (Data = 0x8A28)
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x1FF000E4 (Data = 0x05408A28)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x1FF000E4 (Data = 0x8A28)
Reading 32 bytes @ address 0xF0000FD0
Connected to 127.0.0.1
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x1FF000FC (Data = 0x89B8D002)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x1FF000FC (Data = 0xD002)
Received monitor command: reset
Resetting target
Downloading 192 bytes @ address 0x08000000 - Verified OK
Downloading 6072 bytes @ address 0x080000C0 - Verified OK
Downloading 28 bytes @ address 0x08001878 - Verified OK
Downloading 8 bytes @ address 0x08001894 - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0x0800189C - Verified OK
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0x080018A0 - Verified OK
Downloading 12 bytes @ address 0x080018A4 - Verified OK
Writing register (PC = 0x 80006d0)
Starting target CPU...
GDB closed TCP/IP connection (Socket 1128)
Debugger requested to halt target...
...Target halted (PC = 0x1FF000E4)
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x1FF000E4 (Data = 0x05408A28)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x1FF000E4 (Data = 0x8A28)
GDB closed TCP/IP connection (Socket 1152)
Restoring target state and closing J-Link connection...
Shutting down...
```

On the other hand, the same code works on a STM32L031K6 of the nucleo board with the ST link disconnected.

**Update 4:*
Since I'm using a custom board, there may be a flaw in the schematics. I don't see any issues with the circuit, but maybe, you see some. There is no crystal since it shouldn't be required regarding the datasheet. There are internal oszillators available.

The `TOUCH` net is just a circuit which connects `GND` to the pin if a button is pressed.

This is the circuit of the STM32L031G6U6.
[image: STM32L031G6U6]

This is the circuit of the LEDs that should be controlled. In the previous code I just try to control the LED with the net label `STATUS_LED`. Since I got the LED to blink while stepping through the code, the Mosfet circuit should work.
[image]

I'm currently very confused why I got so many problems. I tried a second and third PCB of the same circuit, but the problems are the same.

I figured out, that I cannot use any clock configurations although they are offered by the STM32Cube IDE. Using the MSI just doesn't work for some frequencies. The code will stall in the `SystemClock_Config` setting the oscillator or the clock.

- Why the `HAL_Delay` sometimes doesn't work and sometimes it does?
- Why the system doesn't start at all when trying to run the code (even with everything disconnected and just the power supply reconnecting)?
- Why stepping through the code does work but running the code does not?

Comment: Just a guess: `HAL_Delay()` uses the SysTick timer and interrupts as default. Seems there are some troubles with the clock and interrupt settings.

Comment: Thanks for your guess. It may be correct, since I can follow the code until it waits for HAL_GetTick() to be larger than the given wait time. And there may be an infinity loop. But why the lex. turns off? And why it does not work without the HAL_Delay calls. It should flicker but the led is just off.

Comment: For `HAL_Delay` you probably need to check that the systick interrupt handler is set to the right function. This function is probably increments a counter that `HAL_Delay` is polling on.

Comment: Your Systick is perhaps badly set up. If the delay is very short (not 1 second as you want but few milliseconds) you will not see the LED blink.

Comment: But if there is no delay, the LED should be switched on and off very quickly, so that it would be dimmed. But it isn't either. Even if `HAL_Delay` is removed. I assume that the systicks are not correctly handled. On the other hand, using a nucleo board, everything seems to be working.

Comment: "But if there is no delay, the LED should be switched on and off very quickly, so that it would be dimmed. Even if HAL_Delay is removed" No, the instructions will get executed too quickly for you to see the LED change states.

"On the other hand, using a nucleo board, everything seems to be working." Everything works fine on the nucleo because its their standard platform and the CubeIDE configures the clock tree based on the clock input provided by the nucleo hardware. To that end, you should adjust your clock settings based on the clock input that your hardware provides.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, bigwilldos! On my board there is the same STM32L031, just in another package. I don't understand what are the differences between the nucleo board configuration and the one on my own board. The nucleo board can be configured without a crystal as on my board there is no crystal to be configured. I'll try again to configure the clocks another way.

Comment: Ok, there is definitely something weird. Sometimes, but not always, I can step through the code and press on continue and everything works. If I run the project, nothing works. And most of the time, if I press continue while in debugging, it also not works. I just don't understand the problem.

Comment: This whole STM32 thing just acts randomly. I build the project let it run and it works. I rebuild it and it doesn't and I rebuild it again and it works again! Why? And why does the HAL_SYS_CFG_GetBootMode() delivers 0 or 256, but it isn't constant?

Comment: Your config in CubeMX looks ok. Sounds like this is a custom board that's causing you trouble. Do you have an equivalent Nucleo board?  If so, you should try your same code on that. Have you verified the power on your board to make sure it is the right voltage, smooth, and capable of supplying adequate current?  What programmer are you using(st-link, jlink)? Have you tried the programmer on a board that is known to work? Do you have the programmer set to verify that your firmware is written correctly? Rather than your IDE, try erasing, loading, programmer with STM32CubeProgrammer several times

Comment: My custom board has the same circuit on it as the equivalent nucleo board except the missing crystal. But usually it isn't required as noted in the datasheet. I've tried an st-link clone and an original J-Link EDU. The flashed code is verified. I can check another board with the J-Link, but I'm pretty sure, that it'll work. And I'll try the last point with another programmer.

Comment: @bigwillydos On the nucleo board the while loop runs with the led dimmed without the HAL_Delay. On my board it doesn't. The run log says that the target has been halted. But why? If I try to restart by powering down and powering up (with or without a connected debugger) the LED also not flashes.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. The part in altium was not correct. The STM32L031G6U6 which I used is actually for the STM32L031G6U6S, but the name has been STM32L031G6U6. Very confusing.
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The Altium package I downloaded was for the wrong package of the STM32L031. It ia for the STM32L031G6U6S and not the STM32L031G6U6.